# Ubuntu 9.10 screen resize on VirtualBox 3.2.8 on Windows Vista machine

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-9.10

I have installed Ubuntu 9.10 on my VirtualBox 3.2.8.
I installed all the guess additions.

The main feature of the guest additions is not working for me.
That is resizing the Ubuntu on VirtualBox.
I can maximize/minimize or play with the size of the Ubuntu OS on VirtualBox.
But it does not working for me.

I want to figure out the actual issue but I cannot see any way. I can see some static ways but they are not automatic. Every time I need to change the resolution of the Ubuntu OS.

Is there any fix for this ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what the issue is. Can you clarify what you mean by resize? Are you talking about the actual resolution or dynamic size of the partition that Ubuntu is installed on?

Comment: @Peter Yes, I am talking about the resolution.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation: upgrade to VirtualBox 3.2.10. It specifically addresses installing Guest Additions in Ubuntu. In fact, just today I installed the latest Ubuntu (10.10) in 3.2.10, ran `sudo apt-get update` right after the OS finished installing, and GA installed quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I ran the following in 10.10:

```
sudo apt-get install virtualbox-ose-guest-x11
```

and the resolution of my Ubuntu install was able to resize dynamically.